# Starting a database for use in retail store - want access at home, some mac some windows

Tags: sql-server, excel

I soon will be opening a new retail store.  I'm currently tracking all of our product  purchases in an Excel spreadsheet and want to start migrating to a SQL Server database.  I'm pretty new with SQL but have done some basic work in the past.  This is my first time setting up my own SQL database.  I just think if I learn to do it now it will really pay off down the road as I want to query different info quickly vs. doing everything in Excel.

My main needs will be to access the data both at the store as well as at home.  There will be three computers at the store (one in the back office and two at the cash wrap).  These three will all be iMacs.  I also want to be able to have access from home where I have both Macs and Windows.  I'd prefer to be able to access the database directly from home rather than needing to remote into a computer from the store.

What is the best way for me to accomplish the above goals?  The data and processing will be pretty basic as this is a 2,000 sq. foot store so we won't have a ton of inventory.  I'm starting to play with importing my spreadsheet into SQL Server express but I'd prefer not to have to keep multiple instances of the same database to access at different locations.  Am I crazy to try and accomplish this or should it be pretty simple and straight forward?

Thanks.

Comment: host it in the cloud as a SQL Azure database

Comment: Agreed with @MartinSmith here. Maybe also look at some open source inventory tracking software as there is a few options out there. Software development and database development is a task suited for developers and it sounds like opening a store is going to keep you busy and software development might take second place to your core business.

Comment: If you import multiple excel sheets into SQL, it's not going to automatically work out any discrepancies (this sheet say 5 widgets, this sheet says 6 widgets). You might find that an Excel sheet sitting in OneDrive allows you to have a centrally editable sheet. (on all platforms). I only say this because if you're running a business you don't want to have to drop everything and cut SQL code. Having said that, there are many new online tools such as Azure Power Apps that let you get a web enabled database up and running very quickly.

Comment: You're not crazy to try this - you should definitely try it. But the main gotcha is that putting a front end on SQL Server is non trivial. Since you have mac's and PC's you're front end is probably going to have to be some kind of web interface

Comment: Thanks for the comments everybody.  After thinking about it a little more I think what I'm going to do is have the spreadsheet contain all the data and have that stay in sync (either dropbox or google sheets).  This will allow sales people at the store to see the necessary information.  Then at home I will load it into SQL Server so I can do some more analytical work on it through SQL.  Realistically I probably don't need the sales people having access to that.  I thought I'd create some basic functions for them but it is probably just easier for them to search via Excel.